# Find longest subarray whose sum divisible by 3 with O(N) Complexity

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, complexity-theory

i have big question here , if you can see below the code you will see code with O(N) complexity.  im only try  to decrease it to  O(N^2),
Im treid to do it with O(N) but without any secces .

```
private static int f (int[]a, int low, int high)
    {
    int res = 0;
        for (int i=low; i<=high; i++)
            res += a[i];
            return res;
    }

    public static int what (int []a)
    {
        int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j<a.length; j++)
        {
        int c = f(a, i, j);
        if (c%3 == 0)
        {
            if (j-i+1 > temp)
            temp = j-i+1;
            }
          }
        }
    return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Just iterate once over the array, increment a `count` variable if the current item is divisible by 3. Copy `count` to another variable `max` and reset `count` when the current item is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Can you explain your code first? You said you want to find a *subarray*, but all you are returning is a *number*.

Comment: First of all, please add a few example (input arguments, expected result).

Comment: Hey geys, couple of exemple :

Answer (score 0):

couple of exemple :
`int[] a={1,2,4,1};` output : 2 ==> if you can see (1+2= 3 ) ,(2+4=6) so those is %3=0 ==> beacuse that the number is 2 beacuse is two subarray that giving me %3 to be =0.
`int[] a={3,4,4,2};` output : 2
`int[] a={3,3,3,3,0,1};` output : 5
`int[] a={3,2,7,6,6,1};` output : 5

Comment: Don't insert examples as an answer! You can append the examples to your opening post instead.